# parse json faster in java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have the scenario. I will send a request to the web service, and get the XML response. Used XML class from json.lib to convert the XML to JSON. Time to get response from the web service is 7s, and parsing takes anywhere around 4-8 seconds. Then all i need to do is, parse the JSON to an much desired format.

Ex : JSON after convert the XML

```
{"Response":{"Response":{"type" : [{1,2,3}]},"value":[{100,200,300}]}}
```

I am converting this JSON to below format

```
[{"type":1,"value":100},{"type":2,"value":200},{"type":3,"value":300}]
```

The problem is, this particular conversion of JSON -> JSON takes hell-a-lot of time, so instead of display result within 15 secs, it's taking around 25 secs, and the worst part is, if JSON is bit big, it takes upto 90 secs. Can you tell me what should i do to make this fast?

I am using Spring 3.0 + Tomcat 6.0.29 + json.lib for JSON parsing.

**Updated :**

Code i am using to convert the XML to JSON.

```
JSONObject ResponseObj = XML.toJSONObject(elementToString.getelementToString((Element)Responses.item(0)));
```

Comment: Could you share an example of a JSON response?  Spending 90 seconds of time parsing JSON seems like a lot of time unless the JSON itself is a bit odd.

Comment: Please provide us with the info/code *how* you are currently transforming the JSON, so we can give you hints if it's possible and where to improve your code.

Comment: I would get a better internet connection and/or a better pc. 90 secs are endless to parse..

Comment: Can you please post your code for the json-to-json conversion?

Comment: why do json-to-json at all? why not xml-to-object and object-tojson using [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) ?

Comment: @All. The need to convert json-to-json object it we have some set of JSON Objects format that we need to follow, because we have 3 different API for performing single operation. So we made a universal JSON format, send request to all 3 WEB-Services, get response and parse them to that unified format.

Comment: hmmm... SOAP is supposed to be the universal format for webservices?

Comment: The interesting datum here is, "how big are the JSON files"?  Really good parsers can do a hundreds of thousands of lines a second.  If your files are enormous, then maybe you have a really different problem.  If your files are small, then your parser library must be terrible.

Comment: JSON files were around ~5MB! But the XML file size was more than that! I couldn't get the exact numbers but putting the XML in some XML formatter took more than a minute!

Comment: That's pretty big. (What kind of data is going back and forth?).  Estimating:  30 chars/line means 5Mb is 100K lines.  A really good parser should be able to read this in 1-2 seconds.   People writing parsers for stuff like json probably aren't expecting 100K line inputs; your json parser might just be stupid-slow.   But there's another lesson here:  shipping things around as text is a sure-fire way to waste bandwidth and computer processing power (json is bad here; XML is much worse).   But then I didn't design the web world.

Comment: @IraBaxter The data is the search result of flight schedules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been more than a year old since I've posted this, but I felt I need to close this question with my solution, in case if someone faced exactly the same scenario!

So all I did was, parsed the JSON, and sent it as it is to the HTML page, in which I've done the parsing of data as I liked using lodash plugin! It was much faster and since conversion happened at front-end, we displayed data as and when it is parsed, like 5 after 5 and it felt fast. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

First, why json-to-json? Is it necessary or is it 'nice to have'?

I would think that the problem is object creation, first you create lots of objects by parsing the xml to DOM, then you must build a new object-tree for the xml->json conversion, and then again you create another object-tree for the json->json conversion. And object creation is one of the more expensive operations you can do in Java.

To prevent all the object creation, look at event driven xml and json handling like [SAX](http://www.saxproject.org/) for XML and [Json Simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) and/or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) for JSON.

But ofcourse the fastes possible solution would be to handle the XML SAX style and skip all the transformations.

Comment: My result is an SOAP Response, and i mapped it to an Object using JAXB. Will Jackson be of any help in that scenario?

Comment: If you are using JAXB take a look at Jersy's JSON features: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#json.jaxb.approach.section

Answer (score 0):

You can test speed in json parser in [xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org). Generally `xstream` uses pull parsing what is really fast in case of XML (pull parsing is the same idea like behind `Java StAX` - newer standard in `Java` after `SAX` and `DOM`).

When I used `xstream`, parsing from `JSON` to java object hasn't been noticable (RCP application with embedded browser).

Comment: XStream again took the same time as json-lib. Not much of help